# sort binary datetime

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, vb.net

Just a quickie, I stored a binary datetime to database. I get this binary value from

```
DateTime dtNow = DateTime.Now;
long lgNow = dtNow.ToBinary();
```

My question is, can I use these binary (long) values for sorting?

Thanks!

Comment: " I stored a binary datetime to database." - Why?

Comment: Yes, but you will have to sort binary numbers.

Comment: What's wrong with storing dates in a date data type in sql server?
*Every time* I've seen someone try to reinvent the wheel they **failed miserably.** Microsoft employs some very smart people and sql server is a very good product. what makes you think you can outsmart it?

Answer (score 1):

No. The binary value returned by ToBinary has Int64 type, but is not semantically an Int64; it contains packed fields. Sorting by these values is not guaranteed to sort the underlying dates in chronological order.

Ref: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tobinary%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

What you probably want is `DateTime.Ticks`, like this...

```
DateTime dtNow = DateTime.Now;
long lgNow = dtNow.Ticks;
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.ticks%28v=vs.110%29.aspx